# Evaluating Formula In Object for JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var data = {
  'buyRate': ['Buy Rate', 0.15, 'enteredData.numberOfTransactions * enteredData.buyRate',
  'setupFee': ['Setup Fee', 0.00, 'enteredData.setupFee'],
  'numberOfTransactions': ['# of Trans.', 10, 'enteredData.numberOfTransactions']
}
```

*`enteredData` is another object that pulls values from user inputs. Created after this object but it does exist*

What I want to do is use the third position in the array as a formula to calculate a 'Total' which is displayed using a script like this (I run this after the object is created so the object keys are not undefined):

```
for (var key in data) {
  var formula = data[key][2];
  // evaluate the formula by some magic
  var sum = new Function('return '+formula);
  document.getElementBy(key+'Total').value = sum;
}
```

Because I am working in Google Sites using eval() is not an option for me. I've tried using `var sum = new Function('return '+formula);` and it's not working for me. I don't get any errors. And console.log displays (no other information):

```
function anonymous() {
  return data.numberOfTransactions * data.buyRate
}
```

Not sure how else to approach this problem. Would appreciate a push in the correct direction.

Comment: In your example the code `data.numberOfTransactions * data.buyRate` is multiplying two arrays. I don't think that's what you want to do. Also, in your use of `Function` the reference to `data` may or may not point to your `data` object. [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) does not create closures the way writing a regular function would, they reference the global scope.

Comment: Also, you never evaluate the function. You'd need to call `sum()`.

Comment: Evaluating user-supplied code through `eval` or some `Function()` construction is potentially dangerous. Is there no better way? This is usually a sign of bad code structure.

Comment: @JorgeCabot Thanks. That was my mistake when I created my example here. I updated to code. The formula actually references another object. Also, I forgot to call `sum()`. That got it working.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly I'll be interested in any other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers here helped me but after I figured out that Google Sites also don't allow creating function constructors I approached this a different way that allowed me keep the logic that I wanted.

Below the is the updated object. I simply rewrote my formula as a tiny function that I can call:

```
var data = {
  'buyRate': ['Buy Rate', 0.15, function() {return enteredData.numberOfTransactions * enteredData.buyRate;},
  'setupFee': ['Setup Fee', 0.00, function() {return enteredData.setupFee;}],
  'numberOfTransactions': ['# of Trans.', 10, function() {return enteredData.numberOfTransactions;}]
}
```

This will run the formula every time I call it and not when the object is rendered.

My updated `For...in` loop looks like this:

```
for (var key in data) {
  var sum = data[key][2];
  document.getElementBy(key+'Total').value = sum();
}
```

Hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: This is a better approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

If Google disallows `eval`, I would guess they also disallow running user-supplied code using your `Function` trick.

However, if this is not the case, you need to slightly change your function. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) states:

> Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which the Function constructor was called.

You'd therefore need to pass the correct variables, like this:

```
for (var key in data) {
  var formula = data[key][2];

  // create function
  var my_func = new Function('data', 'return ' + formula);

  // pass data explicitely
  var sum = my_func(data);

  document.getElementBy(key+'Total').value = sum;
}
```